# How can I demonstrate to voters that a question is less trivial than it seems?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I came across this question:
[How should I calculate the average speed by road segment for multiple segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794664/average-speed-by-road-segments)

Which has attracted a straightforward "RTFM" answer... And that answer is wrong.

However, the correct answer requires a certain level of math understanding that may not be obvious from the question unless you already know the correct answer (namely, that averaging rates using the arithmetic mean produces incorrect results).

I've provided clarifying details in my answer, and also edited the question itself to illustrate a necessary understanding of the problem (which, I admit, the asker may or may not have possessed at the time he wrote it).

The question is otherwise complete; it identifies the problem and the expected outputs, complete with sample data for each.

I would like to draw attention to this question, and get your input on the situation: what else could I have done to save this question?

Comment: You can just vote reopening the question. No need to discuss each and every closed question here.

Comment: The question wasn't necessarily closed because it is a "RTFM" question; it's rather that "here's what I want, how do I do this?" type questions with zero code or visible effort tend to be frowned upon. I'll happily chip in a reopen vote though

Comment: There is a single edit to the question, which changes the desired output, made by you. This isn't preceded by any conversation with the OP, as far as I can see. So you're arguing that OP doesn't know what they want, but you do, without asking them?

Comment: Looks more like *gimmetehcodez* at the first glance. (Can't comment more, as I dunno bout sql)

Comment: There is a mathematically correct way to average velocities that is not arguable, Both the OP and the close-voters missed it, that doesn't change the fact that the question is more sophisticated than it seems at a first glance

Comment: How exactly did you know the person was after the harmonic mean, given the lack of description in the question (and the fact that the harmonic mean was not what the sample output was)?

Comment: Maybe each segment is a time not a distance?

Comment: The question did say 'road segments'

Comment: I find that *RTFM* as something rude and offensive and it should not be used on SO.

Comment: RTFM has been part of programming vernacular for nearly four decades @KФ.

Comment: However, [the historical consensus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23628/how-should-we-deal-with-rtfm-comments) is that its usage should be frowned upon. Meh.

Comment: Telling someone to RTFM (without actually helping them solve their problem) is not OK @FrédéricHamidi, no argument there. That, however, is not how the term was used here.

Comment: I think you are making a great argument here Uri, but at the same time you've picked perhaps the worst possible example for it. The question has a lot of other problems (lack of research being the more significant) and there's no evidence the OP was looking for the harmonic mean (or even that they would understand it). Also, your edit - as explained in Maroun's answer - is iffy. I upvoted your answer in the main site for going a step further than the simplistic solution, but I don't see any reason to upvote this Meta discussion.

Comment: There was no such comment here @KФ.

Comment: That comment is unrelated to this discussion @KФ. I'm puzzled why you felt compelled to comment about it here. Just flag it and move on.

Comment: Why was the question deleted ?

Answer (score 26):

The question doesn't demonstrate minimal understanding of the problem being solved (I really miss this option). It should be closed. I really don't understand the reopen votes.

As a side note, I think your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34794664/revisions) should have been a comment. If I were reviewing it I would have rejected it - changes to actual code or data should be done by OP and not by editors.

Comment: Why do you come to the conclusion that because the question doesn't demonstrate minimal understanding of the problem being solved it "should be closed" when that close reason no longer exists?

Comment: Ironically, the best indication of the lack of a minimal understanding here was the incorrect expected average shown in the output table. **Which the editor corrected!** And then explained in his answer. In other words, **the fix you assert should have been rejected was the very thing needed to fix the problem you identify in the question!** This is yet another reason why "minimal understanding" was a poor close reason; if folks are going to assert that it is both impermissible to lack understanding *and to provide it*, we arrive at a place where answers may only help those who need it least.

Comment: @MartinSmith Because I do expect "I tried X", at least. We don't want Stack Overflow to be "How do I X in Y". Please, let's expect the minimal... At least let them share their thoughts with us.

Comment: It is irrelevant to future people searching on the topic of averaging speeds whether the OP tried anything or not. Lack of research is a possible reason to downvote, not close, except if that makes the requirement unclear or too broad etc.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think that helping people that don't try to demonstrate the minimal is not for their good, that's why I prefer to close it. Maybe they'll be trying to do something and learn by themselves before getting a ready solution.

Comment: Why does everybody keep delimiting sentences with commas, lately? I don't get it. Sentences end with a full stop, like this. That's taught in English class when you're 4 years old, and differs in no Western language that I'm aware of. (I have no idea how others are.)