# SO question deleted while in Meta discussion

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I previously asked [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314789/trigger-happy-close-voters) Meta question with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794664/average-speed-by-road-segments) SO question.

The Meta question was about "why the SO question was closed", so needless to say that I disagree with the deletion of that question.

But the current situation is bizarre: I cannot delete the Meta question that refers to a broken link (because the original SO question was deleted).

Either delete the Meta question as well, or undelete the SO question.

Comment: Note that the link doesn't get broken for users with [>10k rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: Well, just raise a mod flag is enough when you want delete/undelete a post but you can't do it yourself. However no neeed another meta post.

Comment: related: [Impose a 24 hour voting freeze on questions being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269191/839601)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Undeleted, for now. Irritatingly, one of the delete voters *also posted a link to the meta discussion*, so this wasn't entirely ignorance; I'm not quite sure what the point of that was.

For future reference, when bringing up a question for discussion on meta please try to avoid inflammatory titles and focus on the merits of the question instead. Perhaps lay out some of the subtleties you feel folks have overlooked rather than merely asserting that they exist. Try to be persuasive rather than argumentative.